# I have string object contains Oadate need to be write in excel cell as date format

Tags: c#

I am writeing excel using  Epplus excel package  fetching data from Db table in this Table all columns are type of string

in this table some columns contain oadate  as a I have write this date in excel as date format

this is my excel writeing code

> ```
>         if (!errorRecords.Any() || !propertyList.Any()) return fileInfo;
>         using (var excelfile = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
>         {
>             var worksheet = excelfile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ErrorData");
>
>             worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(errorRecords, true, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default,
>                 propertyList.ToArray());
>
>             WriteHeaders(headings, worksheet);
>
>             excelfile.Save();
>         }
> ```

```
    errorrecords is list of data which i have write in excel
```

> ```
> Here i Set Headers for excel file which i am creating ,
> here i try to set style for this column but not working
> ```

```
 var count = headings.Max(x => x.Position);
     var datecolumns = headings.Where(x => x.ColumnDataType == 
     ColloSysEnums.FileDataType.Date);
     foreach (var column in datecolumns)
     {
        worksheet.Column((int)column.Position).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
     }
```

I want to save date in excel in actual format
In excel column format is custom with format (yyyy-mm-dd) but cell contain oadate number as it is 
i wnat this cell data with yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.FromOADate`?

Comment: That is unlikely to be a `OaDate` value as it is in the year 3335. Today has the value 42019, the value you have is an order of magnitude larger. Did you miss a decimal point? How sure are you that this is an OaDate?

Comment: @SonerGönül it's machine/ephoc time

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: why not, don't you have any appointments at `11/4/3335`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know, Outlook apparently doesn't roll appointments out that far into the future. I guess I'll just have to wait and see.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DateTime.FromOADate(double d)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx), as you have the number for date in string so you need to convert it to `double` for passing to `FromOADate`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(Double.Parse(yourDoubleString));
```

> FromOADate Returns a DateTime equivalent to the specified OLE
>   Automation Date, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx).
>
> The d parameter is a double-precision floating-point number that
>   represents a date as the number of days before or after the base date,
>   midnight, 30 December 1899. The sign and integral part of d encode the
>   date as a positive or negative day displacement from 30 December 1899,
>   and the absolute value of the fractional part of d encodes the time of
>   day as a fraction of a day displacement from midnight. d must be a
>   value between negative 657435.0 through positive 2958465.99999999,
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter, he can parse it to get double.